# Rounding off decimal places in my final output

Tags: java

My code reads:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaHexagon {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       double side, area;

       System.out.print("Enter the side:");
       side = s.nextDouble();

       area = ((3 * Math.pow(3, 0.5) / 2)) * Math.pow(side, 2);

       System.out.print("The area of the hexagon is " + area);
    }
```

}

The error message I am getting says: for 6.6 being the length of the side the answer should be 113.17 but I am getting 113.17219976 and so on. I tried adding **double roundOff = Math.round(side*100)/100;** but  I can't get it to function right.

Comment: Do you need the number to actually be truncated, or just it's printed representation?

Comment: The result is correct with a lot of decimals (maybe even irrational). So it can only be about the printed representation

Answer (score 5):

Use this: `System.out.printf("The area of the hexagon is %.2f", area);`

Answer (score 1):

To cut some fractional part, you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", area);
```

To apologize that I have duplicated the answer I wrote my own function which is cutting the decimal part at the specified position:

```
public static double cutDecimalPart(double number, int position) {
    int power = (int) Math.pow(10, position);
    int big = (int) (number * power);
    return (double) big / power;
}
```

Comment: why are you duplicating the answer?

Comment: @prabodhprakash when I started to write it, there were no other answers.

Comment: I have modified my answer not to be duplicate ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hexagon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       double side, area;

       System.out.print("Enter the side:");
       side = s.nextDouble();




       area = ((3.0 * Math.pow(3.0, 0.5) / 2.0)) * Math.pow(side, 2.0);

       System.out.printf("The area of the hexagon is %.2f", area);

    }
```

}

That's the fixed code and it is running smoothly. Thanks for the help @alex-chermenin & @wojciech-kazior

Comment: It would be a cool if you could accept my answer as the correct one. I have upgraded it, cheers!